# How to hide a data set (line graph) in a LineChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am showing two line graphs using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library and I'm trying to hide a `Dataset` on button click.

Can any one suggest me how to hide a line graph from Line chart on button click? [image: a line chart]

Comment: Assuming that you have a method for display the chart, in the new OnClick Method call the chart method, but now only with the Data of the pink line graph.

Comment: @TimeToCode  Yeah, i can do that but here problem is total chart will recreate again. So here with out disturbing i want to hide. can i do that?

Comment: Wait, you are filling the chart with an ArrayList?

Comment: Yes, i am filling with ArrayList.

Comment: You are using two ArrayList? or just one?

Comment: One ArrayList only.

Comment: Maybe you only need to delete the currently chart, and create new one with the data of the pink line graph. The following link contains the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Getting-Started) of MPChart,

Comment: I found the method `clear()` to clear the chart, use this. Check this link [Clear Mothod MPChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Miscellaneous)

Comment: Yeah i tried that. its creating with one line graph. its working but here its recreating.. anyway thank you so much for replies.

Comment: @TimeToCode Thank you so much i tried with clear() and invalidate() methods its working.

Comment: Yeah i will accept it. after clear() have to call invalidate() method. put answer with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the method `clear()` to delete all the information of your chart, and after that you need to use the method `invalidate()` to refresh the entire chart.

The MPAndroidChart documentation are here: [MPAndroidChart Documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Miscellaneous)

Answer (score 9):

It is also possible to hide the `DataSet` from the chart without removing it from the charts data.

This can be done by using the `setVisble(boolean)` method of the `DataSet` class.

```
LineDataSet dataSet = ...;
dataSet.setVisible(false); // hides the set
chart.invalidate(); // redraw
```